# Can't send photos from this account - WTH?

Tags: nexus-5, photos, google-hangouts

I have a Nexus 5 running 4.4.4.  I have a Google Apps account that I use for GMail, G+, etc.  My wife has a standard GMail account with G+ enabled.  We chat back and forth using the Hangouts feature rather than SMS as much as possible.  This works fine.  We can send each other photos through SMS, and it works fine.

She can send me photos using the hangouts feature, and it works.  I cannot send her photos.  The message

> Can't send photos from this account

Pops up at the top of the screen immediately.  Is this a feature I've disabled in my account somewhere?  How do I fix it?

Comment: What is your wife using for hangouts, if it's an iPhone this seems to be an issue. Is it online, is it on Android? There is an issue where you need to delete your G+ account and reactivate it but consider that the nuclear option. Is hangouts trying to send it via MMS?

Comment: She's on a Galaxy S4.  I will not nuke my G+ account. I'm pretty active on it.  It works if I send using MMS.  It does not if I use hangouts (and this is on wifi - I have a usage-based carrier and I'm trying to reduce usage).

Comment: I have a nexus 5 and an S4 here and I'm sending pics without any issue. I presume you tried uninstalling updates to hangouts and G+ and re-installing everything? I'm a bit lost for ideas to be honest, it sounds rather localised to the 2 of you. I'll keep looking.

Comment: I think I found it.  *My* account is a Google Apps account, and Hangouts was disabled at the domain level.  I've changed it, but it could take 24 hours before changes propagate.

Comment: Lucky you if it works. I was about to post an answer.

Comment: OK, if that solves the problem, don't forget to come back and post an answer, to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting *at the domain level* was the issue.  I enabled it, and it starting working a few hours later.

This shouldn't be an issue for standard Google accounts - just Google Apps accounts.

Comment: Do you know by any chance where to find this option in new shitty Google Admin Console that they've "upgraded" recently ?

Comment: Apps / Google Apps / Talk/Hangouts gets to some settings, but I can't seem to find a setting for photos.  Maybe it's always enabled when Hangouts is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [enable Google Photos for the Domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6304946). Once I did this, I was able to send photos via hangouts.